# CSS: Weird extra border in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a weird problems with [one of my Arabic sites](http://saudigamer.com/).

See that gray rectangle with the red heading in the homepage? right underneath it shows up a horizontal gray border in IE8 that I just couldn't get rid of unless I remove the border under the black headings below, which I don't want to do.

There's even an extra space between those two elements that's not supposed to be there. You can view the page in Firefox vs. IE8 to see what I mean.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a duplicate h2 under the episode_summary producing in ie8.
u should try validating the site first. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Although this isn't really the answer, but reminding me of validation did lead me to the issue. It was a missing </a> that caused all of this. Thanks. :)